# Couldn't get Publish subscribe with Azure service bus and rebus working

Tags: azureservicebus, rebus

```
var bus = Configure.With(adapter)
            .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Error)) 
            .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBusAsOneWayClient(connectionString))
            .Options(b => b.SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts: 1).Start();

var bus = Configure.With(adapter)
             .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole())
             .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(connectionString, "subscriber1"))
             .Options(b =>
             {
                 b.SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts: 2); 
                 b.SetNumberOfWorkers(3);
                 b.SetMaxParallelism(3);
             })
             .Start();
```

The first bus is for the publisher and the second bus is for the subscriber. I expected that this will create a queue named subscriber1 and a topic with the message type.

But instead it created a queue called subsciber1 and some topic called messages_azuremessage__messages. And the handler for the subscriber never received the message  (I had the subscriber running when I start the producer).

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you found a topic created by Rebus, you must have more code than what you have shown so far :)

Could you maybe show the parts where you

```
await bus.Subscribe(toSomething);
```

and where you

```
await bus.Publish(something);
```

?

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I had   bus.Subscribe<AzureMessage>().Wait();  line commented out by a mistake. And that is the reason why the consumer didnt read the message. Thank you very muh!